# use yolov4 face detection with face_recognition

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, face-detection, dlib

Can I use yolov4 for object detection and use the face_recognition library to recognize detected faces, or do I need to use face detection provided by the face_recognition library in order to use its face recognition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

face_recognition library uses `dlib`'s inbuilt algorithm specific for face-detection. It's claimed accuracy is 99%+. You cannot change that algorithm to YoloV4 or any other.

The network architecture for face_recognition is based on ResNet-34, but with fewer layers and the number of filters reduced by half. The network  was trained on a dataset of 3 million images on the Labeled Faces in the Wild (LFW) dataset.

Have a look at Davis King (the creator of dlib) and Adam Geitgey (author of face_recognition) articles on how deep learning-based facial recognition works:

[High Quality Face Recognition with Deep Metric Learning](http://blog.dlib.net/2017/02/high-quality-face-recognition-with-deep.html)

[Modern Face Recognition with Deep Learning](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-4-modern-face-recognition-with-deep-learning-c3cffc121d78)

However if that is not sufficient for your case, you can train YoloV4 to detect faces and then after detecting, crop that face and give that as input to face_recognition library.

```
import face_recognition

picture_of_me = face_recognition.load_image_file("me.jpg")
my_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(picture_of_me)[0]

# my_face_encoding now contains a universal 'encoding' of my facial features that can be compared to any other picture of a face!

unknown_picture = face_recognition.load_image_file("unknown.jpg")
unknown_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_picture)[0]

# Now we can see the two face encodings are of the same person with `compare_faces`!

results = face_recognition.compare_faces([my_face_encoding], unknown_face_encoding)

if results[0] == True:
    print("It's a picture of me!")
else:
    print("It's not a picture of me!")
```